# file line search doesn´t match

Tags: php, file, title

Im trying to create system which recognize if article has title (under title, there must be $recognizer, here set to "test"). I want to use this:

```
<h2>TITLE</h2>
test
<hr>

<?php
$file = file('article.php');
$title = $file[0];
$recognizer = $file[1];
echo $title;
echo $recognizer;
echo '<hr>';

if ($recognizer == 'test') {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'unsuccessful';
    echo "<br>" . $recognizer;
}
```

while i use echo $recognizer, it echoes test, but if() returns unsuccessful. Can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Does it have a linebreak at the end, by any chance? Try `var_dump($recognizer)` to see what you've actually got in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file command retains the new line character by default.

To fix change

```
 $file = file('article.php');
```

to

```
 $file = file('article.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

if you think you may have additional whitespace that could be causing issues with a match
you could filter those out using

```
 array_map("rtrim", $file);
```